# Filtering an audio signal and then reading the meter without sending it to master

Tags: web-audio-api, tone.js

I'm trying to filter a signal and then analyse the values of the filtered signal using Tone.js / Web-Audio API.

I'm expecting to get values of the filtered signal, but I only get -Infinity, meaning that my connections between the nodes are wrong. I've made a small [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryLj4wv2/3/) demonstrating this, however in my use-case I do not want to send this node to the destination of the context - I only want to analyse it, not hear it.

```
osc.connect(filter)
filter.connect(gainNode)
gainNode.connect(meter)
console.log(meter.getLevel())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you tested the code in Chrome because there is a problem with Chrome which causes it to not process anything until it is connected to the destination. When using Tone.js that means you need to call `.toMaster()` at the end of your chain. I updated you fiddle to make it work: https://jsfiddle.net/8f7abzoL/.

In Firefox calling `.toMaster()` is not necessary therefore the following works in Firefox as well: https://jsfiddle.net/yrjgfdtz/.

Comment: If you want the code to work anywhere, just have it connected to a `GainNode` with a gain of zero, and connect that to the destination.  Alternatively, if this is for visualization, then perhaps using an `AnalyserNode` is good enough.  For chrome, this node must have its output disconnected or connected to the destination.

Comment: @RaymondToy I want to do some other processing and filtering on the signal, the ```AnalyserNode``` is not what I'm after - am I right to assume I have to move these processes into an ```AudioWorklet```?

Comment: Depends on what processing you want to do, so I can't give a definitive answer.  However, if you're basically using this to visualize, you can also use a `ScriptProcessorNode` to do whatever you want.  The `ScriptProcessorNode` is deprecated, but it's not going away any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I've found out that I need to have a [scriptProcessorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createScriptProcessor) - which is apparently no longer recommended - so looking into [Audio Worklet Nodes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/audio-worklet)